# Quotient of algebraic curve

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Say we have an algebraic curve $C:s^6 = t^6 + 1$ defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$, and the automorphism $\phi :(s,t) \mapsto (s,\xi_6t)$ (we assume this is defined over the base field). I am trying to construct equations for the quotient curve $C/<\phi>$ and the corresponding quotient map. Magma seems do be able to do it, but I can't find any literature on the topic. Anyone knows how to do this or has a reference? Very much appreciated!

Comment: Here's a start. $G=\langle \phi \rangle$ is a cyclic group of order $6$. Let $A=\mathbb{F}_p[s,t]/(s^6-t^6-1)$. $G$ acts on $A$, and the coordinate ring of the quotient curve $C/G$ is the subring $A^G$ of $A$ consisting of $G$-invariant elements. Now, any $f$ in $A$ can be written as $f_0+tf_1+\dots+t^5f_5$ where $f_j\in \mathbb{F}_p[s]$. Written in this form, the action of $G$ is easy to understand. Such an $f$ is invariant under $G$ if it satisfies the system of equations (a Vandermonde matrix) corresponding to being fixed by every element of $G$.